# How to use express router with react

Tags: express, reactjs

Im working on a react + node project. Im new to both these technologies. In the front end I use react router to navigate through forms. So, if we use react router from the front end, what is the use of using express router from the back end? And how exactly we will use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React router is a client side router to navigate between pages. Express router is a server side router to define API endpoints.